# Execute one test case several times with different fixture each time

Tags: c++, boost, fixtures, boost-test, mt

I have a test case that I want to execute for different states of database. I insert objects to DB in fixture (and I'd like to keep it that way). I want to make method for initialization of DB virtual and specialize fixture for different configurations in DB.

One way I can think of is to do something like:

```
void doTest(){
    //test code here
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test1, fixture1)
{
    doTest();
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test2, fixture2)
{
    doTest();
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test3, fixture3)
{
    doTest();
}
```

But is there a cleaner, neater way?
Or maybe I shouldn't do this altogether? I will appreciate any advice from testing experts.

Comment: Are you trying to create test scripts for .cpp file? I would create a script

Comment: If you use Google Test instead of boost test, you can use the "TestWithParam" and "INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P" to instantiate/run a test multiple times with different values: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Value_Parameterized_Tests

Comment: @KRUKUSA Sadly I cannot use scripts here (these will be automatically executed)

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Thanks, seems good, but I have to use boost test framework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE` to instantiate multiple tests:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestModuleName
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

struct Fixture1 { int i; Fixture1() : i(1) {} };
struct Fixture2 { int i; Fixture2() : i(2) {} };
struct Fixture3 { int i; Fixture3() : i(3) {} };

typedef boost::mpl::vector<Fixture1, Fixture2, Fixture3> Fixtures;

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(Test, T, Fixtures, T){
    std::cout << T::i << "\n";
}
```

Will print

```
1
2
3
```

This code instantiates an own test case for each type in the `mpl::vector` 'Fixtures'. Each Fixture type will be passed in as `T` (second parameter of `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE`) and `T` will be used as fixture for the test case (last parameter).

### Caveat

Because of the template nature of the test case (class) you need to prepend `T::` to access the fixtures members to indicate that they are (template parameter) dependent names.

### Improvement

Because `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE` is so generic, one might want to define a handy "shortcut" which is more explicit about what is being done:

```
#define MULTI_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(NAME, TPARAM, ...) \
        typedef boost::mpl::vector<__VA_ARGS__> NAME##_fixtures; \
        BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(NAME, TPARAM, NAME##_fixtures, TPARAM)

MULTI_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(Test, T, Fixture1, Fixture2, Fixture3){
    std::cout << T::i << "\n";
}
```

As you can see it somewhat hides the `mpl::vector`. I think it would be best to define this macro in its own header which also does `#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>` to avoid missing the dependency. The fixtures list name is the name of the test case plus '_fixtures' so it should hopefully not clash with existing names and be somewhat meaningful.

Comment: @Dino: I added another convenience macro which makes the interface nicer :)