# Is there a way to test nontype templates using Boost Test?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I am using Boost Unit Test to perform unit test for my project. I need to test some non-type templates, however seems that using the macro `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(test_case_name, formal_type_parameter_name, collection_of_types)` I can test only typed templates. I want to use a `collection_of_types` not composed by `{ int, float, ...}`, but `{0,1,2, ...}`.

Here an example of what I want to do:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::list<0, 1, 2, 4, 6> test_types;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE( my_test, T, test_types )
{
  test_template<T>* test_tmpl = new test_template<T>();

  // other code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always wrap static constants in a type. For integral types there is [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) or indeed the Boost MPL analog:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b631df3aeb69cf)**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE sotest
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN

#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

template <int> struct test_template {};

typedef boost::mpl::list<
    boost::mpl::integral_c<int, 0>,
    boost::mpl::integral_c<int, 1>,
    boost::mpl::integral_c<int, 2>,
    boost::mpl::integral_c<int, 4>,
    boost::mpl::integral_c<int, 6>
> test_types;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(my_test, T, test_types) {
    test_template<T::value>* test_tmpl = new test_template<T::value>();

    // other code
    delete test_tmpl;
}
```

Prints

```
Running 5 test cases...

*** No errors detected
```

### BONUS Tip

To save on typing you can use a variadic template alias:

```
template <typename T, T... vv> using vlist =
    boost::mpl::list<boost::mpl::integral_c<T, vv>... >;
```

Now you can define the list as:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8f7975e85e2e8de)**

```
using test_types = vlist<int, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6>;
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend the test case to take a fixture?

Comment: @Christoph90 not sure. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22065661/85371?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I saw this but it was not immediatly clear how to adapt it since I needed to use a templated fixture struct but also use the same template parameter in the body of the test for specialization of some other templated entities. A simple solution for this is to extend the fixture with a static member that stores the fixture's template value parameter...